# Can a multiclassed Warlock/Sorcerer create Pact Slots with the Sorcerer’s flexible casting?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, sorcerer, spell-slots

In dnd warlock spell slots are max level so if you make a first-level warlock spell slot using Sorcery points does the spell slot become max level is this possible and if it is can you make infinite spell slot by making a 1st level spell slot and it becoming a 3rd level slot then making it into 3 Sorcery points using 2 to make a 1st level slot and it becoming a 3rd again gaining a spell point every time you do this thus making infinite spell slots?

what I'm basically asking is that in and 5e does a 1st level warlock spell slot become a 3rd because it says that all your spell slots are max level.

Comment: Duplicate of: [Can a multiclass sorcerer make spell slots for their other class using sorcery points?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/156737)

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: I've marked this as a duplicate, but that's totally fine! Different ways of asking questions is a good thing as others may be able to find the answer more easily. If you don't think this is a duplicate, please let us know what is missing and we may reopen.